# CoreData breaks To-Many relationship when entity assigned to multiple parents

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I think I might be missing something in the way `core data` operates but I have two entities: **Collection** and **Item** (10 properties). Collection has To-Many relationship items (no inverse, no action on delete, ordered).

If I add `NSManagedObject` Item to different Collections, SOMETIMES the previously created collection loses relationship to it's items. Let me explain what I mean by using word SOMETIMES.

There are 400 unique Items presented in different collections. I load collections from the webservice. And there are 2 separate calls:

1) First call returning small collection (let's call it Collection A) of 6 Items with all of their properties (10).

2) Second call returning 5 collections of 400 Items (each collection has same items in different order). Among 400 items, there are also 6 returned previously (Collection A is a subset of full collection)

After first response, all data is parsed and saved. After second call new data is parsed and saved. If afterwards I request collection A - it has no items (relationship faults have nothing to do with it).

PLOT TWIST: If before parsing each new collection I request item count of Collection A - the relationship remains intact and all the items are available.

Spent 2 days on this already. Have no clue what else to check. Context is the same, context is saved after each new entity added. As mentioned before there's no inverse relationship on Item object.

What am I missing here?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be some sort of inconsistency somewhere deep in the CoreData code. I can't find any other reasonable explanation except a bug in CoreData.

Having inverse To-Many relationship on **Item** seems to cover the bug.

Comment: I think you are correct - the problem is the missing inverse relationship.  From the CoreData programming guide, "It is highly recommended that you model relationships in both directions, and specify the inverse relationships appropriately. Core Data uses this information to ensure the consistency of the object graph if a change is made (see Manipulating Relationships and Object Graph Integrity)."

Comment: Thanks for the input @pbasdf. Still it's odd to see core data lose the relationship just SOMETIMES... I can break my code removing simple log statements (and these statements don't do anything else except fetch data required for logging).